# How to access variable from tkinter class

Tags: python, tkinter

I have built a simple one-page application using tkinter, whose script is executed when the program is started. A variable called self.index is created at the same time, which contains a certain number. I need to import this number in another script of the program, but this turned out to be tricky.
Here is my tkinter class:

```
class ChatApp:
    index = 0

    def __init__(self):
        ChatApp.index = 0
        self.create_index()
        self.window = Tk()
        self._setup_main_window()

    def run(self):
        self.window.mainloop()

    def create_index(self):
        connection = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
        cur = connection.cursor()
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO chats (content) VALUES(Null)")
        db_getid = pd.read_sql('select id from chats order by id desc limit 1', connection)
        ChatApp.index = db_getid["id"][0]
        connection.commit()
        connection.close()

    def _setup_main_window(self):
        f = open('files/' + str(ChatApp.index) + ".txt", "w+")
        self.window.title("Chat")
        self.window.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        self.window.configure(width=500, height=600, bg=background_color)

        head_label = Label(self.window, bg=background_color,
                           fg=text_color, text="#"+str(ChatApp.index), font="font_bold", pady=10)
        head_label.place(relwidth=1)

        line = Label(self.window, width=480, bg=background_gray)
        line.place(relwidth=1, rely=0.07, relheight=0.012)

        self.text_widget = Text(self.window, width=20, height=2, bg=background_color, fg=text_color,
                                font=font, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.text_widget.place(relheight=0.745, relwidth=1, rely=0.08)
        self.text_widget.configure(cursor="arrow", state=DISABLED)

        scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.text_widget)
        scrollbar.place(relheight=1, relx=0.974)
        scrollbar.configure(command=self.text_widget.yview)

        bottom_label = Label(self.window, bg=background_gray, height=80)
        bottom_label.place(relwidth=1, rely=0.825)

        self.msg_entry = Entry(bottom_label, bg='#2C3E50', fg=text_color, font=font)
        self.msg_entry.place(relwidth=0.74, relheight=0.06, rely=0.008, relx=0.011)
        self.msg_entry.focus()
        self.msg_entry.bind("<Return>", self._on_enter_pressed)

        send_button = Button(bottom_label, text="Send", font=font_bold, width=20, bg=background_gray,
                             command=lambda: self._on_enter_pressed(None))
        send_button.place(relx=0.77, rely=0.008, relheight=0.06, relwidth=0.22)

    def _on_enter_pressed(self, event):
        msg = self.msg_entry.get()
        self._insert_message(msg, "You")

    def _insert_message(self, msg, sender):
        if not msg:
            return

        self.msg_entry.delete(0, END)
        msg1 = f"{sender}: {msg}\n\n"
        self.text_widget.configure(state=NORMAL)
        self.text_widget.insert(END, msg1)
        self.text_widget.configure(state=DISABLED)

        msg2 = f"bot: {chat(msg)}\n\n"
        self.text_widget.configure(state=NORMAL)
        self.text_widget.insert(END, msg2)
        self.text_widget.configure(state=DISABLED)

        self.text_widget.see(END)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = ChatApp()
    app.run()
```

I first tried importing the entire tkinter class and then using

```
index = ChatApp.index
```

to get the value of the index. That actually works so far. But this causes the interface to be opened a second time. So this short code section causes a complete call of the class ChatApp, which I want to avoid.

Comment: The index is the same for all the instances?

Comment: each user is assigned its own entry in a database and thus its own ID (index). With every start a new index is generated

Comment: ok but for every run of your app the index is the same, inside the single app? or you have multiple instance of ChatApp?

Comment: the database uses a auto increment so every call of my app gets a new index

Answer (score 0):

If in each instance the index is the same you can use a static value like this instead of `app.index`

```
ChatApp.index = <some value>
```

And when you need it

```
index = ChatApp.index
```

Comment: do you mean by instance for each start of the program? Because index gets a different value each time

Comment: for instance i mean every call of `ChatApp()` in same execution, but please try my solution and let me know if it work

Comment: where would I need to call ChatApp.index = <some value>? I get also the error "AttributeError: type object 'ChatApp' has no attribute 'index'" when I use index = ChatApp.index

Comment: you have to put it every time you use `self.index`

Comment: Ok it worked nearly. I created a class variable index and set it to 0. This brings a new problem. When importing, the value remains at zero. I have edited my code above to show my current status

Comment: you need to share index between multiple threads?

Comment: yes I need to call the index of the app.py (there is the ChatApp class) in my chat.py script

Comment: how do you create threads?

Comment: the whole thing is a program for a chatbot. in chat.py the answers of the bot are created based on the questions of the user. At the same time every time the bot gives an answer or the user asks something, so the chat.py is executed, the correct .txt file is opened and the texts are inserted there.

Comment: so, at certain time you call chat.py (the code of the answer) and when the operation in completed you close it?
If yes, how do you call chat.py?

Comment: In my class under _insert_message you can find "chat()" this function is imported from chat.py and is for calling the this script

Comment: i fixed it by passing the chat() function in my app.py another variable that includes the index. This allows the chat.py script to use the correct index. Thank you all for your help